# Button stays highlighted after being clicked - Unity3D 4.6 GUI

Tags: unity, gui

Sometimes, after clicking a button created by unity's new UI Button, the button stays in its highlight state. Note that Button script has `Color Tint` set as it's `Transition` property and the `Interactable` checkbox is checked.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `Navigation` property of buttons is set to `Automatic` by default, allowing you to navigate through buttons using arrow keys.

If you disable this by changing the `Navigation` property to `None`, buttons will not stay highlighted.

Comment: Something important to add to it: If you set the `Navigation` to `None`, you 1. can't use your keyboard or controller to navigate to/from it and 2. trying to get it with `GameObject.Find` will return some type of object that isn't really usable because everything about it is `null`. So basically: If you use `None`, you have to either drag the button onto a public variable in the Inspector or instantiate the button at runtime to get a functioning reference to it. Tested with Unity 2017.3.1f1.

Answer (score 1):

*(In addition to the accepted answer, this is another answer if you are not able to set the `Navigation` property of buttons to `None` in your context.)*

You can also use [`UnityEngine.EventSystem.SetSelectedGameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.SetSelectedGameObject.html) to manually deselect the button. For example:

```
private void DeselectClickedButton(GameObject button)
{
    if (EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject == button)
    {
        EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(null);
    }
}
```